# Получаю данные GPS не на всех устройствах

Tags: java, android, gps

Здравствуйте, есть android приложение, в котором после авторизации перед выводом информации в `ListView` я должен запросить эту информацию от API и в параметрах есть долгота и широта. Я использую для определения местоположения стандартные инструменты: `LocationManager`,  `LocationListener`.

Проблема в том, что не всегда это происходит быстро (скорее из за холодного старта GPS приемника) и не на всех телефонах удается получить данные о местоположении.

Есть проверенные и надежные способы получать данные GPS? Мне нужно их получить и прекратить работу для экономии энергии, ведь GPS используется на одном Activity.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Хороший способ делать это через Google Play Services :)